# Insert string where the cursor is

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I would like to insert text where the cursor is currently, so I have the below code

```
    NSString *contentsToAdd = [myData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSMutableString *tfContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[self.myTextView text]];
    // add content where the cursor was 
   [tfContent insertString:contentsToAdd atIndex:myCursorPosition.location];
  [self.myTextView setText:tfContent];
   [tfContent release];
```

This works as below

```
    Hi
    HiFriend
```

I want to leave one space before and after appending the text (hi Friend).

So how should I go with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
NSString *contentsToAdd = [myData objectAtIndex:row];
NSMutableString *tfContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[self.myTextView text]];
// add content where the cursor was 
NSString *contentsToAddPadded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", contentsToAdd];
[tfContent insertString:contentsToAddPadded atIndex:myCursorPosition.location];
[self.myTextView setText:tfContent];
[tfContent release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *beginning = [self.myTextView.text substringToIndex:currentRange.location];
NSString *ending = [self.myTextView.text substringFromIndex:currentRange.location];
self.myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@% @% @",beginning, contentsToAdd, ending, nil];
```