# Issue - Insert text works only for first time , the second time it appends to the end of the text

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitextview, uipickerview

[URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379333/insert-string-where-the-cursor-is/10379468#comment13381118_10379468) I am adding text inside the uitextview using uipickerview.

Currently i am adding the text as below ( did select row method )

```
self.myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.myTextView.text,
            [myTierThreeData objectAtIndex:row]];
```

This works fine but i wanted to insert text where the cursor is so i did the below

```
-(void) pickerViewShown:(id)sender{
  myCursorPosition = [self.myTextView selectedRange];
}
```

When ever the pickerview is shown, taken the cursor position in the member variable.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSString *contentsToAdd = [myData objectAtIndex:row];
NSMutableString *tfContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[self.myTextView text]];
// add content where the cursor was
NSString *contentsToAddPadded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", contentsToAdd];

[tfContent insertString:contentsToAddPadded atIndex:myCursorPosition.location];
[self.myTextView setText:tfContent];
[tfContent release];

myCursorPosition = [self.myTextView selectedRange];
}
```

the above code works for the first time but when try to add next text , it appends the text at the end.

please let me know what is wrong with the above code

Comment: first thing is to try nslogging myCursorPosition.location in didSelectRow

Comment: when nslogging the for the first time it prints correctly when i place the cursor between the two word , it shows the cursor position location as total string length.what can i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably setting the text for the text field **resets the cursor position to the end**, so the only chance you have is to **calculate the new cursor position yourself**:

- When starting the picker view, remember the original cursor position
  (like you do now) in *myCursorPosition*.
- Every time you append text,
  add the text length to *myCursorPosition*, and use that value for
  inserting the next text.

Comment: hi, can we show cursor inside the textview when selecting option inside the uipickerview( currently i think my texview losts the focus)