# NSLog statement for Cursor Location is showing wrong value, when calling from ViewWillAppear method

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a textview in my app so to insert text in the current cursor position I tried [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380477/issue-insert-text-works-only-for-first-time-the-second-time-it-appends-to-th/10380977#comment13384959_10380977)
which was working fine.

Now I encounter one issue.

> when I tried to call the aCenterBtnClicked( ) method inside the
>   viewWillAppear( ) function  , it shows as the current location as
>   "2147483647 location" (  NSLog(@"%d location",
>   myCursorPosition.location); ).
>
> But when I hide the  function call of aCenterBtnCliked( ) method from
>   the viewWillAppear() method , it prints the current cursor location as
>   "0 location" (  NSLog(@"%d location", myCursorPosition.location); ).

I want to know why the cursor location is changing when calling the aCenterBtnCliked() method in the viewWillAppear function

How to solve this issue?

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//-----------------------------------

    [self aCenterBtnClicked];

}

//===================================
-(void) aCenterBtnClicked{
//===================================

  myCursorPosition = [self.myTextView selectedRange];

  NSLog(@"%d location", myCursorPosition.location);

}
```

Comment: The formatting of this question hurts my eye.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set your curent position in button click only thats why it will change if same code you put in viewwillapper it will also change.
you can directly call like this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
  myCursorPosition = [self.myTextView selectedRange];
 }
```

Comment: even when i tried your code  to print inside the viewwilappear it shows as below "2147483647 location". pls let me know

Comment: how this happen. Because method is same, main point is content inside method if both are same then output will be same check your code. again.